# Motion Chart in Beamer

Tags: beamer, charts, swf

I am looking for a way to integrate a Google motion chart in a `beamer` presentation. I read that I can integrate a swf movie, but Google charts work online. Ok, I can insert a link to the webpage, but it would be really nice if the chart is actually in the presentation.

How do I do this? Or should I use another motion chart software? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: As an aside, I think this question might boil down to 'Can I include web content in a PDF with pdfLaTeX?' given how web-driven Google is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I have put the motion chart on a separate html page. Then put a screenshot in the beamer presentation, with `\href` command that links to the webpage. Not the best integrated solution, but for now...